# VariableSerialization.config Custom Config file

Tags: patch-configuration

Hope you all are well. I am new in Sitecore. So,I have few queries to clear my doubts. I have shared a picture which is a part of config file.

1. In the picture why we used **xmlns:role** and **xmlns:env ?**
2. Inside the **role:require** attribute can I set any random text like **demo/test** or I need to set the predefined text like **Standalone or ContentManagement ?**
3. Inside the **env:require** attribute I can see there are two value set for two different parts. What is the meaning of **env:require="user"** and **env:require="dev or qa or prod" ?**
   [image: Config File]

Comment: Welcome to Sitecore Stack Exchange. For SEO purposes, replace your screenshot with xml snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `role` and `env` is used in order to allow a rule-based configuration. This allow you to set configuration specific for given role or for given environment without a need to deploying different files to every separate Sitecore role or environment.

Full documentation can be found here: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/platform-administration-and-architecture/use-a-rule-based-configuration.html

2. For the `role:require` attribute you should use one (or more) of Sitecore roles which are:

- ContentDelivery
- ContentManagement
- Processing
- Reporting
- Standalone

In theory the setting will allow any other texts but I cannot think of any real live use case when you may need it.

More about roles can be found here: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/platform-administration-and-architecture/define-the-server-role.html

3. Those 2 setting means that if in `web:config` there will be setting:

`sourceFolder` variable will be set to `D:\project\src`. And if there will be any of `dev`, `qa` or `prod` in `web.config`, value of the variable will be set to `/App_Data/unicorn`.

More to be read here: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/platform-administration-and-architecture/add-a-custom-rule-to-your-configuration.html

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. It will help me a lot.